# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript

I'm using this script in my file to shown error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'" in console.
How I fix it?
Error is shown at the PHP tag which is defined in the script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>  
           <script type="text/javascript">  
           google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});  
           google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);  
           function drawChart()  
           {  
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([  
                          ['Car', 'Number'], 
                          <?php  
                          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                          {  
                               echo "['".$row["car"]."', ".$row["number"]."],";  
                          }  
                          ?>  
                     ]);  
                var options = {  
                      title: 'Percentage of branded Car Services',  
                      //is3D:true,  
                      pieHole: 0.4  
                     };  
                var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));  
                chart.draw(data, options);  
           }  
           </script>
```

Comment: Your code it is on a js page or php page? I hope it is a php file.

Answer (score 0):

Your while,

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
{  
   echo "['".$row["car"]."', ".$row["number"]."],";  
}
```

the last echo will print a "," and this can generate your problem.

I recomand to build an array and then use echo with an implode().

Comment: @Brij I need your source result to understand where are the problems. Ctrl+u (view source) on you html page and then copy and paste here the result (only this function). I want to see how it is renders.

Comment: `
 function drawChart()  
{  
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([  
['Car', 'Number'], 
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\FY_project\admin\welcome.php</b> on line <b>34</b><br />
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: arr in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\FY_project\admin\welcome.php</b> on line <b>36</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  implode(): Invalid arguments passed in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\FY_project\admin\welcome.php</b> on line <b>36</b><br />
]);
`

Comment: function drawChart()             {  
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([  ['Car', 'Number'], 
<?php
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($arr))
            $arr = array('car','number');
            echo implode(" ",$arr);
          ?>
          ]);  
          var options = {  
          title: 'Percentage of branded Car Services',   
          pieHole: 0.4  
          };  
         var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));  
                chart.draw(data, options); }
I write this code in my file.

Comment: You have multiple problem here. You can try to solve the php errors(the errors are very clear, you must try to fix them). I can not give you a solution because i don’t know your entire code.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot place php inside javascript however you can echo javascript in php.